# iPhone Multi-View Rotation Hell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, autosize

This is my first post on here and I'm very new to iPhone developing, so please bear with me.

I have an app which has a few view controllers and each view controller has a few nib files that it controls and some of the nibs have more than one view. There is a toolbar throughout the app, controlled by the root view controller.

After lot's of searching, I have got rotation working on every screen, except one.  I haven't got them to load in the correct orientation, but I guess that's a different question.

In my nibs that have more than one view, I can select the autosizing options only on the original main view.  On the views that I have added, which I load using insertSubview, I can select the fixed margin options, but not the width and height resizing options.  I am using Xcode 4.

My 1st Question, is why I am unable to select the resizing options on the additional views?

Sorry, I had to delete the images I put in here, showing what I mean, to be able to post.

Anyway, that is not my main problem, I just want to know, out of curiosity, why I can't select the resize options.  I have found a way around it in the code.  In the function where I load the subview, I add [viewName setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

E.g to load the view that I have named shiftStart, I use:

```
- (IBAction)loadShiftStart:(id)sender {
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:shiftStart atIndex:0];
    [shiftStart setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
}
```

Now here is my problem.  I have a nib file that has 3 views, view which is the main view that loads first, rotaStart, which loads as a subview when a button on the first view is pressed and shiftStart, which loads as a subview when a button on the first view is pressed.  rotaStart and shiftStart are almost identical, with a title, a text block, a Yes button and a No button.  The only difference is the text in the box, and which view is loaded if you click on the Yes or No buttons.

I have all the same resize and margin options selected, in Xcode, for the title, text block and buttons and as far as I can tell, the code that loads them is identical (see code below), but shiftStart rotates correctly and rotaStart does not.

```
- (IBAction)loadRotaStart:(id)sender {
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:rotaStart atIndex:0];
    [rotaStart setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
}

- (IBAction)loadShiftStart:(id)sender {
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:shiftStart atIndex:0];
    [shiftStart setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
}
```

Can anyone tell me why rotaStart is not rotating, when the phone is changed to landscape please?

Sorry this explanation has got a bit long winded.  I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking at this, with a similar problem, [@longball](https://twitter.com/#!/longball) solved it for me.  Somehow I had managed to add a second view over the top of the base view, complete with Labels & Buttons.  Deleting the extra view fixed the problem.